# Can you confirm this bug on NSTokenField?

Tags: macos, nstokenfield

I found the following bug for `NSTokenField`, on `OSX 10.9`.

**I would like to know if there is also this bug on `OSX 10.8` and if you can reproduce the bug on OSX 10.9**.

An `xcode` project showing the bug is available at [this link](http://www.fast-files.com/getfile.aspx?file=67681).

---

Here is what I did.
The screen:

[image]

(the `textField` is a `NSTokenField`)

Then, in a delegate for this `NSTokenField`, put the following code

```
- (NSArray *)        tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField
        completionsForSubstring:(NSString *)substring
                   indexOfToken:(NSInteger)tokenIndex
            indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)selectedIndex
{
    return @[@"Jojo!!"];
}



- (id)                        tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField
       representedObjectForEditingString:(NSString *)editingString
{
    return @"Jojo the cat" ;
}




- (NSString *)              tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField
     displayStringForRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject
{
    return @"Jojo" ;
}
```

You'll see, it bugs. It's too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked with other users. It's a bug, and it's filed.